# Equivalent command to build (on WDK 7) with WDK 10

Tags: windows, static-libraries, msdn, wdk, kmdf

I have some really old scripts using the build command for compiling with WDK 7. A sample command to build a static library is:

```
build /F /g /w /b /c /Z /jpath %BUILDROOT%
```

What is equivalent command I can use to compile the same with WDK 10?
Also where can I find documentation on the usage of the build command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While going through a [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/develop/building-a-driver) of MSBuild I came across this:

> **Important** Starting in Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8, MSBuild replaced the
>   Windows Build Utility (Build.exe).

So that's it - no build command for WDK 8+.
Converting the earlier project into a WDK 10 format - by generating the vcxproj files, I was able to build it.

Comment: This does not say anything I did not already say. If you want help you should give people credit for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has replaced Build with [MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx). The reference is [MSBuild Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx). Note that Visual Studio uses MSBuild, even for WDK projects. It will take time to create VS projects but if the code is to edited more than a little it will be worth doing that.

There is a chance however that you can just change Build to MSBuild.

Comment: Well, this doesn't sound entirely correct. According to [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/develop/building-a-driver), starting from WDK 8, MSBuild replaced the Windows Build Utility (Build.exe).
Thanks for pointing out to MSBuild.
P.S. MSBuild though replaces build.exe doesn't follow the same syntax. Both are very different in that aspect.

Comment: I am sorry, you are correct. I did look at many other things before replying but I **did** miss something important.

Comment: I revised my answer.